# How to get all input controls which are of type file in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to get all the file upload controls on my page, Im adding multiple file upload control so i dont have any idea how many they can be but i have to get all of them in jquery. Im using asp.net mvc and jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
$(':file').each(function(){
  // your code to handle input type files.
});
```

Or:

```
$('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
  // your code to handle input type files.
});
```

**More Info:**

http://api.jquery.com/file-selector/

Answer (score 1):

When do you want to get the input field?
after clicking a button? or changing the input field? if you add dynamic the input field than you can maybe better use the live option.

```
$('input[type="file"]').live("blur",function(){
        $('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
              // you can put your code here
            });
    });
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/live/

above code is from **jQuery 1.4**

Better give more information next time